# Eclipse: coping with different coding styles when committing to repository?

Tags: eclipse, svn, coding-style

I am in a team of developers who all have their own unique ways of styling their code.

For me I like to have new lines for my braces when using controls or loops. Other developers like having a trailing brace on the same line.

What I want to know is with Eclipse you can format code to your style when you view it. However is it possible either through Subversion or with some Eclipse addon that will change back the code styling to a format we have all agreed should be on the repository.

This would mean there is consistency.

Is this possible?

Here is a diagram to show you what I mean:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN automatic code formatting on check in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017953/svn-automatic-code-formatting-on-check-in)

Comment: This is not a duplicate as A: its for a different IDE and B: using a different SVN tool