# Having A Separate View Java Code Style and Committed Style

Tags: java

Is there a translator between my view of the code (ex: I like 2 spaces) and what is saved or committed? Ideally, I would view my code style and it would transparently handle the stuff in the back end when I commit or save.

This is not a duplicate of [SVN automatic code formatting on check in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017953/svn-automatic-code-formatting-on-check-in) because in that question, they want to apply formatting rules on commit. If I were to pull the changes, then I would be stuck with the formatting rules. Essentially, that post only solves half the problem. What about my personal preferences?

This question is how do you achieve both?! There's some standard format is used on the committed code. However, when I'm browsing it locally, I have some plugin or applications that displays it with my preferences, but will maintain the rules when I commit.

Let me add an example to make this more clear.

When I'm editing I want it to be displayed like this:

```
public class Classname
{
}
```

When it's committed, I want it to be committed like this:

```
public class Classname {
}
```

When someone else changes it, commits it like this:

```
public class Classname {
    public Classname() {
    }
}
```

And then I pull it, it should look like this:

```
public class Classname
{
  public Classname()
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: "committed" where? And why can't your IDE help maintain the right code style *while* you write the code? Or asked another way, why would you want your code to look differently when you first write it and when you later modify it?

Comment: because I like it look one way, and the team likes it to look another way

Comment: I'm not sure you understand. I like my code to look a particular way that is different from the coding standard. I want to maintain this view while still adhering to the coding standards when it's committed.

Comment: I don't think that exists. I also agree with recommendation in [linked duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017953/svn-automatic-code-formatting-on-check-in): **Don't**. If you are truly unable/unwilling to adhere to the coding standard of your team/company, then perhaps you should accept that you're not a team player and not work on a team anymore.